Book about RNA structure
I am looking for book recommendations about the structure of RNA molecules (in particular, functional non-coding RNAs, such as ribosomal RNA, riboswitches, rybozymes, etc.)
I really liked "Introduction to Protein Structure" by Carl Branden and John Tooze. Is there some book out there doing for RNA what Branden & Tooze did for proteins?

Have you tried yet to find anything in particular? For example what does a book have that a review paper like this doesn't?

@MaximilianPress That's not talking much about RNA structure? No mention of riboswitches, for instance. Seems the emphasis is on coding RNA.

That article is entitled "structure and function of nucleic acids"- it seems that you are not actually looking for a general purpose RNA structure reference, but rather one that is specifically concerned with catalytic RNA. You might consider making that clearer, because most people will jump right to backbone structure and mRNAs. have you done any research on your own already? If you have then it might be helpful to see it and to understand why it isn't what you want.

@MaximilianPress In my question I mention specifically non-coding RNAs (so, not mRNAs). Some examples are catalytic RNAs like rybozymes, but also riboswitches (which are not catalytic), ribosomal, and others. I have read mostly about riboswitches, and more general things like https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/rna/article/abs/geometric-nomenclature-and-classification-of-rna-base-pairs/0D16AEB8C228306F9003E43276B91AAC (or anything by E. Westhof). Does that give a better idea?
